# How does the Teamwork Band Work?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

In Mario RPG, after you beat Jinx for the last time, he gives you the Teamwork Band which apparently increases the rate that your action gauge fills but it's not clear on how much.

This [site](https://game8.co/games/Super-Mario-RPG-Remake/archives/434668#hm_2) gives some good guidance on how your combo affects the speed that the gauge fills and it says that the Teamwork Band helps, but it's not specific on how much it helps.

For example, each hit could potentially increase the gauge between 1-4% and every 10th hit gives it a 10% bump. Does the Teamwork Band double that or perhaps guarantee the 4% or something else?

Right now, I've got good accessories for everyone, so I'm trying to figure out if it's worthwhile to switch an accessory for this one before 3D Culex. Along that line, does the accessory help if the wearer isn't in the active party? I'm assuming it does because that was the case with the signal ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It expands the range the gauge fills

I finished the Culex fight a few days after making this post and thought this was the case, but that fight's not one I felt comfortable with trying to do without paying full attention, so I wasn't totally sure.

Tonight, I reopened the game and did a bunch of random encounters in Land's End to see how the gauge was reacting. I observed the following:

- Each successful timed hit causes the gauge to fill as little as 1% or as much as 8%. This is an increase on the previous threshold of 4%.
- There is no impact on the 10-hit bonus. That remains static at 10%.
- The effects of the Teamwork Band function regardless of whether the teammate it's equipped on is actively in the party or not.

Whether one should or should not use the Teamwork Band is mostly going to come down to how important Triple Moves are to your playstyle. For most normal fights, they make no difference for me. However, for the fights against Culex and Engine 023 Booster, I did find it necessary to regularly use the Healing Rainbow triple move. Shortening the time between uses of that skill could be the difference between success and failure.

Comment: Excellent research!  I wasn't paying attention and let my previous bounty expire so I started a new one to reward your effort

Answer (score -2):

#### I don't think you're going to get an answer.

All I could find on the subject was essentially what you just said. The devs have also not released any official numbers, so that's out of the question as well.

It's possible (and maybe even likely, due to the amount on random stuff floating around on the internet) that **someone** somewhere found some numbers, but it's unlikely they'd get to you.

I would say, however, that it probably makes the percentage you gain have a higher low point and a higher cap.

Also, I believe that the teamwork band works even if you're **not** in an active team.

Comment: I feel like your use of bold or heavy text does not really have any consistency, so your answer reads a little annoyingly: obvious is the "someone somewhere found some" without "numbers" having been bolded, but "works" and "not in an active team" are neither logical highlights without the context and/or direct structure sentence.

Comment: Someone would need to do research in-game in order to find concrete numbers as there don't appear to be any online.  But it's not impossible to do so, and it doesn't seem unreasonable to ask as many people would like an answer to this question

Comment: @ChaseSandmann It would be very hard though, because it's not sure even how the teamwork band helps you. Someone would also have to spend a lot of time comparing lots of numbers to see exactly how it helps, and most people won't be willing to do that.

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic I think you're overestimating the level of effort that's needed. I spent a little less than an hour just writing down some notes on the gauge changes and noting how the scenario changed (active party member or not). I don't think my answer is absolutely rigorous, but if it was possible to exceed the 8% threshold, it didn't occur in that time frame. And if you can exceed it but it's extremely rare, then it might as well not exist for the purposes of casual play.